# how to keep the style after click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 buttons and each button have a diferent style when it is pressed, but when I do click in other side I lost the style of the button.

```css
.bar-serv {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bar-opt1:focus {
  border-bottom: #7ebf10 solid 2px;
}

.bar-opt2:focus {
  border-bottom: #1F589A solid 2px;
}

.bar-opt3:focus {
  border-bottom: #73afe7 solid 2px;
}

.bar-opt4:focus {
  border-bottom: #e73827 solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chooseServ" class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="p-20" style="display: inline;">options: </p>
    <a onClick="method1" class="bar-serv bar-opt1 p_lr_20">option1</a>
    <a onClick="method1" class="bar-serv bar-opt2 p_lr_20">option2</a>
    <a onClick="method1" class="bar-serv bar-opt3 p_lr_20">option3</a>
    <a onClick="method1" class="bar-serv bar-opt4 p_lr_20">option4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: :focus property will only allow the properties to active when they are being used then it will become normal.

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: Add code snippets like this

Answer (score 0):

You are using The `:focus` CSS pseudo-class that gets triggered when the user clicks or taps on an element. This is usually used on form fields

Try using the `:active` CSS pseudo-class instead that gets triggered when the user presses down the primary mouse button and ends when it is released.

Comment: active not ative :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CSS!

```
bar-opt1:hover{
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```